# Render Spring MVC to String or PDF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to render a Spring MVC controller to a String to create a PDF with it using iText. Because the application is behind Oracle Access Manager I can't URL request to the page's URL and save the output to a String, I need to do render the page without making another HTTP request.

My goal would be to do something like the following:

```
MyMvcController controller = new MyMvcController();
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("TemplateName");

...
modelAndView.addObject(someObject);
etc, etc
...

String html = controller.render(modelAndView);
...
render in iText to a PDF
...
```

I can already render the markup using Flying Saucer + iText, I'm just having a heck of a time capturing the controller's output to a String. Any thoughts? I'm open to not rendering to a String first, the end result just needs to be a PDF that I can attach to an email and I need to be able to dynamically add data to the JSP that I'm rendering.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are using jsp as the view technology - if so, the rendering is not controlled by Spring, but is dispatched to the container to be rendered(`dispatcher.forward(request, response)`). Like you are finding, I doubt if there is a way to intercept the response in the controller layer at all, as an alternative let me recommend this approach:

1. Use a templating engine like [Freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/) , or [Stringtemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) to generate the html, this way the specific html that you require can be generated independent of Spring MVC.
2. Use the html generated above to run it through iText/Flying Saucer to generate the pdf.

**EDIT**

After a little more thought, another approach that is feasible is simply writing a servlet filter to intercept requests to your specific controller request mapping, this filter can intercept the html response, convert to pdf using itext and streaming out the pdf.

Answer (score 2):

As @Biju Kunjummen already said the rendering is done in the view not in the controller. The controller only prepares the model, and the view adds the model data to the static content and renders it.

The default view technology in SpringMVC is JSP. PDF could be seen as another view technology, and SpringMVC already has provisions to use PDF for the view. Rather than forwarding to a JSP view you would forward to a PDF view.

Have a look at the Spring's [AbstractPDFView](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractPdfView.html) and check out this tutorial: http://numberformat.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/spring-mvc-with-pdf-output/. Unfortunately this tutorial creates the PDF by hand in the `buildPDFDocument`, which is not exactly what you want. You need to extend the tutorial to

- render a JSP to HTML in `renderMergedOutputModel` method
- use Flying Saucer to take the HTML + CSS to make it into a PDF in the `buildPDFDocument` method.

As the JavaDoc of the `renderMergedOutputModel` method states

> The first step will be preparing the request: In the JSP case, this
>   would mean setting model objects as request attributes. The second
>   step will be the actual rendering of the view, for example including
>   the JSP via a RequestDispatcher.

The code should look something like this:

> RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("some.jsp");
>   request.setAttribute("anotherString", model.getValue());
>   rd.forward(request, response);

There is a trick, though: we don't want to render to the servlet response, but to a separate ByteArrayOutputStream using a wrapper. The `ByteArrayOutputStream` can be used as the input to Flying Saucer. Check the solution for the wrapper here:
[JSP compilation to string or in memory bytearray with Tomcat/Websphere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189094/jsp-compilation-to-string-or-in-memory-bytearray-with-tomcat-websphere)

In the `buildPDFDocument` method you now take the rendered HTML from the Wrapper in form of the ByteArrayOutputStream and use it the render the PDF in Flying Saucer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial: http://technologicaloddity.com/2011/10/04/render-and-capture-the-output-of-a-jsp-as-a-string/

It requires the spring framework and dwr api.

I did not test it yet, but if it works, I wont need velocity anymore to render HTML email templates.